# Create array from specific field of objects that are in a list

Tags: java, android

I'm not quite sure how to word this properly.  I have a list of objects and those objects have getters for specific fields.  I now need to make an array out of the ojbect list, but I only need one specific piece of data.

Is there any way to do this without using an interator which seems terribly inefficient?

This is in the context of an android application.

Comment: Whether you use an iterator or indexed loop, the efficiency will, for all intents and purposes, be the same.

Comment: You're going to have to loop through the list somehow, and as far as I know an iterator is about as fast a way to loop as there is, since there's not a whole lot of overhead.  What makes you think an iterator would be inefficient?

Comment: Bad assumption on my part?  I guess I just thought there might be a way of doing this behind the scenes which was better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this out - the comments below the question are the correct "answer". There does not appear to be a better (or more effecient) way of doing what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // our original list
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // inserting some values
    for(int i = 0;i<100;i++){
        list.add(i);
    }

    // work starts here :

    // select a range of elements based on index
    List<Integer> subList = list.subList(0, 50);
        // list.subList(from index-inclusive,to index-exclusive)

    // create an array to hold your new values
    Integer[] myArray = new Integer[0]; // must initialize

    // assign the part of your original list to this array
    myArray = subList.toArray(myArray);


    // test Result :
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
        // reult :
        /*
         * [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
         * 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
         * 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
         * 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 
         * 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 
         * 47, 48, 49]
         */

    // hope this was what you were looking for
```